# Bash extract parts from string and create csv

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a document with 1+ million of the following strings and I like to create some new structures byextract some parts and create a csv file for it, what's the quickest way to do this?

```
document/0006-291X(85)91157-X
```

I would like to have a file with on each line the original string and the extracted parts

```
document/0006-291X(85)91157-X;0006-291X;85
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this one-liner `awk`:

```
awk -F "[/()]" -v OFS=';' '{print $0,$(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' your-file
```

It parses the fields of each line with taking `/,(,)` as delimiters. Then it prints out the whole line, the 3rd field and the second field starting from the end of the line. The option `-v OFS=';'` prints semicolumns as output field separator.

Comment: Thanks Bentoy13 that's very cool stuff which I didn't think off and works perfectly.